# Google Cloud SSH Strange Failure

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running into a weird issue with the Google Cloud VM interface. I'm working with my team on the same Google Cloud VM project, each with our own instances.

The problem: I am unable to SSH into my instance, yet am able to SSH into my teammates' instances. Whenever I SSH using the google cloud online interface, the SSH keys never transfer properly. Despite deleting and recreating keys for my computer, I always get Permission denied (publickey) (I'm even getting this on the Google Cloud shell). Even stranger: my teammates are able to SSH into my instance. This is a new phenomenon I hadn't encountered a month ago when I first used the VM successfully.

Can anyone provide me with insight as to how to diagnose the issue, and even better, a solution? I can provide debug information if you'd find useful.

Here is output when using the verbosity flag:
[Output using verbosity flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbDVc.png)

Here is the output from Armando's recommendation of using systemctl status google-guest-agent: [check ownership status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhbPO.png)

Here is the output from Anthony's recommendation of creating new keys all in one line. [Anthony's recommendation to recreate keys in gcloud shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njUaj.png)

Comment: In cloud shell try with gcloud again but this time by adding this flag in order to get more information --verbosity=debug

Comment: Most likely the permission and ownership of your home folder is quite messed up. Can you please share the log of your google-guest-agent to the question by running the command `systemctl status google-guest-agent` there you will read why google guest agent is unable to set your key. Looking for your answer.

Comment: Armando, This is what I see:

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Comment: To verify guest [environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei). Assuming permission [issue](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#couldnotconnecterror)

Comment: Reasons and how to troubleshoot for [255 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498795/permission-denied-publickey-freebsd-in-google-computer-engine/57512037#57512037)

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with permissions. What would have had to happen for my permissions to be granted a month ago, yet now nonexistent?

Comment: @jond34, seeing that we do not have a clear insight on what going on in your project, many things could of happened between now and a month ago. However, it would be best to see what permissions you currently have binded to your account. Also, does your instance have a external ip address? Additionally, If you do have all the necessary permissions needed, then we could try running this command: gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME --force-key-file-overwrite --log-http --verbosity=debug

Comment: How do I check these permissions? I have an external ip address. I get a 255 error running this command @Anthony Leo

Comment: @jond34 You can check permissions on GCP by going under the section IAM & Admin > IAM. Additionally, based on the attach error message you included, it would seem that the overall error message you're getting is "permissions denied (public key)", I would suggest trying the answer found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/311894) and let me know if the answer or troubleshoot steps resolves your issue.