# Permission denied (publickey). ERROR: exited with return code [255]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, rstudio-server

I have been trying to figure out this problem for some time now. I have been connecting to my VM to access RStudio (an IDE). I run the following command:

```
gcloud beta compute --project "project-name" ssh "my-rstudio" --ssh-flag="-X"
```

and get the following error:

```
 Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Tried to figure out what was going on, so I used the more verbose flag:

```
gcloud beta compute --project "project-name" ssh "my-rstudio" --ssh-flag="-vvv"
```

The last few lines of that are as such:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/sherifgerges/.ssh/google_compute_engine RSA SHA256:EUjXtb36bMLZr9QytqoCfxvpUgRFNC2mBnr6SCGkp6o explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
sgerges@34.138.44.143: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Any idea what can be going on here? I tried deleting my SSH keys in the `Metadata` section of the console. That didn't work.

Also,

`gcloud compute routes list`

returns the expected `default-internet       default     0.0.0.0/0       default-internet-gateway 1000`

Have tried suggestions in other threads for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I tried stopping/starting the VM via console. That also didn't work, unfortunately :(

Comment: 255 can be due to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498795/permission-denied-publickey-freebsd-in-google-computer-engine/57512037#57512037)

Answer (score 0):

As [ekofman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3534782/ekofman) said, try stopping (totally shutting down) gcloud then starting it, it that did not help go for the references in gcloud manuals
good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This error may be very complicated to troubleshoot, but here is my list of this to check.

- Reboot the VM and confirm there is no memory exhaustion.
- Confirm you have a valid firewall rule allowing the access.
- Confirm you have added your SSH key to 'Compute Engine -> Metadata -> SSH Keys' or 'Compute Engine -> VM instances -> YourInstance -> SSH Keys'
- Confirm that IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy) is enabled and your have added the required firewall rule (Allow ingress 35.235.240.0/20 tcp).
- Confirm if your instance has a Public IP or just Private IP address.
- Confirm if you can access via 'Compute Engine -> VM instances -> Instance -> SSH'
  -Check the target instances SSH service logs (if possible from different location account).

Here you can find the documentation from Google.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh